# Media.net ads integration with SPA(angularjs)

Tags: angularjs

How to integrate media.net ads in SPA(angularjs) website. I have copied and posted the given code in my website but it is not working(http://test.website.paperboy.com/).

```
<script id="mNCC" language="javascript">
    medianet_width = "728";
    medianet_height = "90";
    medianet_crid = "xyz";
    medianet_versionId = "xyz";
</script>
<script src="//contextual.media.net/nmedianet.js?cid=xyz"></script>
```

But it is working for non angular static site(https://test.website.paperboy.com/mobile-view.html).

Comment: What do you mean by "Not working" do you get any errors shown, or logged? Have you installed the relevant libraries on your server?

Comment: there is no relevant libraries required to install in the server. in media.net ads console they give the above code to paste in the website where i want to show the ads. i did the same but its not working and i am not getting any error. But for  the static site which is not made using angularjs it s working.There is also no documentation in the media.net website. So i am not getting anything how to proceed.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot speak for angularjs, but Angular 2 and beyond scrubs out script tags.  Here is the solution for Angular 8.  Note this is for the asynchronous ad code, not the synchronous code posted, but the methodology should be the same in which we are adding a DOM element:

.ts file:

```js
convertToScript() {
      var element = this.script.nativeElement;
      var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.id = 'mNCC';
      script.lang = this.language ? this.language : 'javascript';
      script.type = this.type ? this.type : 'text/javascript';

      script.innerHTML = `
      try {
        window._mNHandle.queue.push(function (){
            window._mNDetails.loadTag(${this.advertisement});
        });
      }
      catch (error) {}`;
      script['data-cfasync'] = 'false';
      const parent = element.parentElement;
      parent.parentElement.replaceChild(script, parent);
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.convertToScript();
  }
```

.html file:

```html
<div #script style.display="none">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

Add the component where you want (inject the advertisement size and id here)

```html
<div id="616415456">
    <app-media-net-ad [type]="'text/javascript'" [advertisement]="advertisement"> 
  </app-media-net-ad>
</div>
```

The advertisement variable should be formated as "ad_id,ad_size,ad_id".  The header code can be added into the header section of your index.html file.

Comment: Yes, the ads are showing here: stockbossup.com.  Note, Angular Universal was also implemented to ensure search.  This was definitely an issue with Google Adsense, and potentially an issue with media.net.